Get Historical Data from Tradingview by using Tvdataseed module issue
I am a algorithmic trader, I want to get historical data from tradingview by using tvsdatafeed module, this is an open source module.
But when I run the code, it give me an timeout error, even I try to use VPN, switch to different country node, but it does not work
Can anyone help me how to fix such issue? I am living in China, I guess due to someone reason: like block google, without VPN I can not load google website
I am not graduate from Computer Science, but as I know if I use VPN like Singapor or US node, the Ip will changed, and it will unlock google, youtube and so on.
Here is my code:
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
tv=TvDatafeed()
# index
nifty_index_data = tv.get_hist(symbol='NIFTY',exchange='NSE',interval=Interval.in_1_hour,n_bars=1000)
print(nifty_index_data)

I get TimeoutError: timed out.
I try to switch different VPN nodes, but it does not work

You need to include a full exception stacktrace for the TimeoutError, it's unlikely anyone will be able to duplicate your network context to figure out a fix otherwise. All I can say is that when I run your code from the USA, it takes about 10-20 seconds and then it returns results without any exceptions. Perhaps if we know the exact location of the error a workaround can be devised.

Thanks for your reply, the problem has been solved, just add one line code:                         os.environ['https_proxy']='http://127.0.0.1:33210'
Since I am using VPN, and I import OS, so I must fill Terminal Protocol. Because you are living in USA, it does not need to do this, but remember I got a warning from Tradingview, they are not allowed to download historialcal data, otherwise they might ban your account, you'd better try to use unlog method

Thanks for the warning, I don't think this is something I need to worry about.

Indeed, as long as we use unlog method, they can not ban our account, but data might be limited.
